# Prove G is Abelian

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $a,b\in G$.

given that $(ab)^k=a^k b^k$ and $(ab)^{k+2}=a^{k+2} b^{k+2}$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$.
prove that $G$ is abelian.

So far my attempt was: $(ab)^{k+2}=(ab)(ab)^k(ab) \Longrightarrow a^{k+2}b^{k+2}=(ab)a^kb^k(ab) \Longrightarrow a^kb^k=b^{-1}a^{k+1}b^{k+1}a^{-1}$

and from here I'm stuck.
I noticed there was a similar question but there was given that also $(ab)^{k+1}=a^{k+1}b^{k+1}$ which is missing in my question.

thanks for your help.

Comment: What you want to prove is false in general. Let $k = 1$, and $G$ be the group found in [this answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/32155/36146). Then of course $(ab)^1 = a^1 b^1 = ab$, and since the group has exponent three it also holds that $(ab)^3 = a^3 b^3 (= e)$. But the group isn't abelian. It's however true for some values of $k$, [eg. $k=3$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737786/let-g-be-a-group-where-ab3-a3b3-and-ab5-a5b5-prove-that-g-i?rq=1). Where did you find this question?

Comment: Its in my course textbook. Thanks for your counterexample!

Comment: Which textbook is it? The classical exercise (found in Herstein) is to prove that the groups is abelian when $(ab)^k=a^k b^k$ holds for three consecutive values of $k$. See for instance http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40996/prove-that-if-abi-aibi-forall-a-b-in-g-for-three-consecutive-integers.

Comment: @lhf I saw this question. I wrote it in my question. It's not a famous textbook so it's not gonna help if I will tell you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement you want to prove is false in general. Let $k=1$ for example, and let
$$G = \langle x,y,z \mid x^3 = y^3 = z^3 = 1, yz = zyx, xy = yx, xz = zx\rangle$$
be the group found in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/32155/36146). Then $G$ is *not* abelian, but $G$ has exponent three. It thus holds that $(ab)^3 = e = a^3 b^3$ for all $a,b \in G$, and moreover it obviously holds that $(ab)^1 = ab = a^1 b^1$. There are some $k$ for which the statement *is* true though, for example [when $k = 3$, the group is necessarily abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1196261/10014). [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/41004/10014) gives more insight on what values of $k$ could make it work.