# Prove that the given group is an Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let G be a group in which $(a*b)^3=a^3 * b^3$ and $(a*b)^5=a^5*b^5$ for all $a,b \in G$. Show that G is an Abelian group ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let $G$ be a group, where $(ab)^3=a^3b^3$ and $(ab)^5=a^5b^5$. Prove that $G $ is an abelian group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737786/let-g-be-a-group-where-ab3-a3b3-and-ab5-a5b5-prove-that-g-i?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let $G$ be a group, where $(ab)^3=a^3b^3$ and $(ab)^5=a^5b^5$. Prove that $G $ is an abelian group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737786/let-g-be-a-group-where-ab3-a3b3-and-ab5-a5b5-prove-that-g-i)

Answer (score 5):

Since $$(ab)^3 = a^3b^3 \Longrightarrow (ba)^2 = a^2b^2;\;\;\;\;(*)$$

and $$(ab)^5 = a^5b^5 \Longrightarrow (ba)^4 = a^4b^4;\;\;\;\;$$

so $$ (a^2b^2)^2 = ((ba)^2)^2= a^4b^4\Longrightarrow b^2a^2 = a^2b^2$$

using $(*)$ we get $$b^2a^2=(ba)^2  \Longrightarrow ba = ab$$

Comment: +John Watson thank you but please can you explain (*) to me that the main point to me ..

Comment: This is correct...though slightly messy, but correct.+1

Comment: $ababab =(ab)^3 =  a^3b^3$ so you can cancel a on left and b on right.

Answer (score 0):

First observe that $(ab)(ab)(ab)=a^3b^3\Rightarrow a^2b^2=(ba)(ba)=(ba)^2$

So,

$(ab)(ab)(ab)(ab)(ab)=a^5b^5$

$\Rightarrow$ $a^3b^3(ab)(ab)=a^5b^5\Rightarrow$ $b^3(ab)(ab)=a^2b^5$

$\Rightarrow$ $b^3(ab)(ab)=(a^2b^2)b^3$

$\Rightarrow$ $b^3(ab)(ab)=(ba)(ba)b^3$

$\Rightarrow$ $b^2(ab)(ab)=abab^3$

$\Rightarrow$ $b^2(aba)=abab^2$

$\Rightarrow$ $b(ba)(ba)=abab^2$

$\Rightarrow$ $ba^2b^2=abab^2$

$\Rightarrow$ $ba^2=aba$

$\Rightarrow$ $ba=ab$.

Comment: How do you justify your second $\;\implies\;$ ?

Comment: multiply $a^{-3}$ and $b^{-3}$ by left respectivlly

Comment: Does not work since, a priori, $b^{-3}a^2b^5$ is not the same as $a^2b^2$.

Comment: @upvoters Please explain your vote. Did you read the post before voting?

Comment: @1Enigma then I get $$a^{-3}a^3b^3(ab)(ab)=a^{-3}a^5b^5\implies b^3(ab)(ab)=-a^2b^5$$and if I further multiply this on the left by $\;b^{-3}\;$ I get$$(ab)(ab)=b^{-3}a^2b^5\ldots?$$ How is the last expression equal to $\;a^2b^2\;$ ? Did I miss anything?

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 I think it would be a good idea to delete this answer as it is basically incorrect...or at least unexplained.

Comment: DonAntonio, I edit my answer. I want to thank you for polite and humble comment.